# Getting soap to run on a Vagrant CentOs machine

Tags: php, php5, vagrant, soap

I have a vagrant machine on my local computer and I am testing an API that requires Soap.

For the life of me I cant get soap to install on the machine.

**Checking phpinfo, I note:**

SOAP    Brad Lafountain, Shane Caraveo, Dmitry Stogov

**Running the script returns:**

Class 'SoapClient' not found in ...

**From the command line I have tried:**

```
# yum install php-soap
Loaded plugins: presto, priorities, security
Setting up Install Process
2522 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Package php-soap-5.5.30-1.el6.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

**In my php.ini file I have added the line:**

```
extension=soap.so
```

(although I am unable to locate the soap .so file).

**I have used puphpet to build my servers and have this for PHP:**

```
php:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '55'
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
            - soap
        pear: {  }
        pecl:
            - pecl_http
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
        date.timezone: UTC
    fpm_ini:
        error_log: /var/log/php-fpm.log
    fpm_pools:
        phpfp_dwt088sfnfb2:
            ini:
                prefix: www
                listen: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                security.limit_extensions: .php
                user: www-user
                group: www-data
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
```

I am not 100% sure of the best way to resolve this.

Comment: What have you done that caused "2522 packages excluded due to repository priority protections"?

Answer (score 0):

If you manually installed the extension (why wouldn't you just add it to your config.yaml?) then you may need to reload the php-fpm service.

Comment: I have very little experience with this to be honest. How would I add soap to the config file? I did take a look to try and work it out but did not get very far...